# Convert class component function to a functional component function

Tags: reactjs

I have class component functions that handle a search function.

```
filterData(offers,searchKey){
const result = offers.filter((offer) =>
        offer.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)||
        offer.expiryDate.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)||
        offer.quantity.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)
    )
    this.setState({offers:result})
}

const handleSearchArea = (e) =>{
    const searchKey=e.currentTarget.value;

    axios.get(`/viewPendingSellerOffers`).then(res=>{
        if(res.data.success){
            this.filterData(res.data.existingOffers,searchKey)
        }
    });
}
```

Now I try to convert these class component functions to functional component functions. To do this I tried this way.

```
const filterData = (offers,searchKey) => {
const result = offers.filter((offer) =>
        offer.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)||
        offer.expiryDate.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)||
        offer.quantity.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)
    )
    setState({offers:result})
}

const handleSearchArea = (e) =>{
    const searchKey=e.currentTarget.value;

    axios.get(`/viewPendingSellerOffers`).then(res=>{
        if(res.data.success){
            filterData(res.data.existingOffers,searchKey)
        }
    });
}
```

But I get an error that says "'setState' is not defined". How do I solve this issue?

Comment: you can't use `setState` with functional components, you have to upgrade to hooks 
learn more about hooks here -> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: You need to do something like `const [offers, setOffers] = useState([])` and then `setOffers(result)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const YourFunctionalComponent = (props) => {
  const [offers, setOffers] = useState()

  const filterData = (offersPara, searchKey) => {// I changed the params from offers to offersPara because our state called offers
    const result = offersPara.filter(
      (offer) =>
        offer?.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey) ||
        offer?.expiryDate.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey) ||
        offer?.quantity.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)
    );
    setOffers(result);
  };

  const handleSearchArea = (e) => {
    const searchKey = e.currentTarget.value;

    axios.get(`/viewPendingSellerOffers`).then((res) => {
      if (res?.data?.success) {
        filterData(res?.data?.existingOffers, searchKey);
      }
    });
  };
  return (
    //To use your *offers* state object just call it like this {offers?.El1?.El2}
  );
};
export default YourFunctionalComponent;
```

**Note:** It is recommended to do null check before accessing nested objects like this `res?.data?.existingOffers`, [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) will help us in this regard.